# python re.sub, substitute a pattern only if it appears at the beginning of a string

Tags: python, regex

substitute a pattern only if it appears at the beginning of a string.
for e.g. `str1 = "abab abadfadsf"`

I only want to remove/replace the "ab" at the beginning of str1, i.e. I want to write an regex so that I can get `str2 = "ab abadfadsf"` from str1 by `re.sub`

how do I do it?

Comment: Did you even bother reading [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `re.sub('^ab', '', 'abab abadfadsf')`
`^` stands for the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 5):

You'd be better off using the builtin string methods for this simple case - a regex is useful for more complex matching, but not required for this.

```
str2 = str1[2:] if str1.startswith('ab') else str1
```